# Is there a way to fetch a gtk app's gsettings values?

Tags: gnome, gsettings

For example, I have Devhelp installed. According to the source code, Devhelp
creates a gsettings id called `org.gnome.devhelp.fonts`, I would like to know
if it's possible to read the value for `org.gnome.devhelp.fonts` while Devhelp
is running.

(Notice that in my system, the key `org.gnome.devhelp.fonts` will not be listed in, for example, the result of `gsettings list-recursively`.)

Comment: Have you tried with this? `gsettings get org.gnome.devhelp.fonts OPTION`

Comment: @Lucio No, `org.gnome.devhelp.fonts` doesn't appear in `gsettings list-recursively`. Apparently I should read more about GSettings and GDbus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never mind. I recently noticed ([1](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-December/msg00402.html)) the key can be access via `gconftool-2`:

```
$ gconftool-2 --all-entries /apps/devhelp/ui
 fixed_font = Inconsolata 12
 use_system_fonts = false
 variable_font = Ubuntu 12
```

I guess up until now (Ubuntu 13.04), the developers of Devhelp haven't fully adopted GSettings.